# JavaScript/jQuery How do you select all Audio Elements created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

I am created elements via javascript in the document.ready.

How do I select all the elements that I created?  I can't find a simple/working answer to this anywhere!

Here is what I tried, but it is NOT working!

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.audioElement1 = document.createElement('audio');
$.audioElement1.setAttribute('src', '/Content/mfile1.mp3');

$.audioElement2 = document.createElement('audio');
$.audioElement2.setAttribute('src', '/Content/mfile2.mp3');

});



function stopAll()
        {
            var cnt = 0;
            $("audio").each(function () {
                cnt += 1;
                this.pause(); // Stop playing
                this.currentTime = 0; // Reset time
            });

            alert("total: " + cnt);
        }
```

My "alert" returns 0 every time/doesn't do anything!

Comment: You haven't add these audio to the document yet.

Comment: You are correct, but...... Doesn't it seem like I added them via javascript!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName('audio')` instead of `$("audio")`.

It returns an array of all audio elements.

[HTML DOM getElementsbyTagName() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp)